# MySQL JSON_OBJECT AGG vs non-AGG, and how it precisely works

Tags: mysql, json

I've been busy with a query that solidifies multiple results in a single group. The table has the following setup

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+------------+
|   dotw   |  start   |   end    | delivery | restaurant |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+------------+
| FRIDAY   | 17:00:00 | 23:00:00 |        1 |        665 |
| FRIDAY   | 17:00:00 | 23:00:00 |        0 |        665 |
| MONDAY   | 17:00:00 | 23:00:00 |        1 |        665 |
| MONDAY   | 17:00:00 | 23:00:00 |        0 |        665 |
| SATURDAY | 17:00:00 | 23:00:00 |        1 |        665 |
| SATURDAY | 17:00:00 | 23:00:00 |        0 |        665 |
| SUNDAY   | 11:00:00 | 23:00:00 |        1 |        665 |
| SUNDAY   | 11:00:00 | 23:00:00 |        0 |        665 |
| THURSDAY | 17:00:00 | 23:00:00 |        1 |        665 |
| THURSDAY | 17:00:00 | 23:00:00 |        0 |        665 |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+------------+
```

This is what I want to achieve, with the expanded JSON format:

```
+------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| restaurant |                            json                            |
+------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
|        665 | {}                                                         |
+------------+------------------------------------------------------------+

{
   "1":{
      "MONDAY":{
         "CLOSINGTIME":"value",
         "OPENINGTIME":"value"
      },
      "TUESDAY":{
         "CLOSINGTIME":"value",
         "OPENINGTIME":"value"
      },
      "WEDNESDAY":{
         "CLOSINGTIME":"value",
         "OPENINGTIME":"value"
      },
      "THURSDAY":{
         "CLOSINGTIME":"value",
         "OPENINGTIME":"value"
      },
      "FRIDAY":{
         "CLOSINGTIME":"value",
         "OPENINGTIME":"value"
      },
      "SATURDAY":{
         "CLOSINGTIME":"value",
         "OPENINGTIME":"value"
      },
      "SUNDAY":{
         "CLOSINGTIME":"value",
         "OPENINGTIME":"value"
      }
   },
   "0":{
      "MONDAY":{
         "CLOSINGTIME":"value",
         "OPENINGTIME":"value"
      },
      "TUESDAY":{
         "CLOSINGTIME":"value",
         "OPENINGTIME":"value"
      },
      "WEDNESDAY":{
         "CLOSINGTIME":"value",
         "OPENINGTIME":"value"
      },
      "THURSDAY":{
         "CLOSINGTIME":"value",
         "OPENINGTIME":"value"
      },
      "FRIDAY":{
         "CLOSINGTIME":"value",
         "OPENINGTIME":"value"
      },
      "SATURDAY":{
         "CLOSINGTIME":"value",
         "OPENINGTIME":"value"
      },
      "SUNDAY":{
         "CLOSINGTIME":"value",
         "OPENINGTIME":"value"
      }
   }
}
```

I've written the following query, but it only works after getting the first value of each dictionary.

```sql
SELECT 
    oh.restaurant,
    JSON_OBJECTAGG(
        oh.delivery,
        JSON_OBJECT(
            oh.dotw,
            JSON_OBJECT(
                'openingtime', oh.start,
                'closingtime', oh.end)))
FROM opening_hours oh
WHERE restaurant = 665
GROUP BY oh.restaurant
```

If I try to `JSON_OBJECTAGG()` or `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` the nested JSON it returns an invalid grouping error.

Do I need to join the query on itself to work? And why does MySQL not understand what I want?

Comment: *In pseudocode, this is what I want to achieve:* No. Show output which matches shown source data strictly.

Comment: Changed the pseudocode into expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As expected MySQL handles grouping in a rather special way. I fixed the problem by joining the query on itself.

```sql
SELECT
    oh.restaurant,
    JSON_OBJECTAGG(
        oh.delivery,
        oh.JSONoh) OpeningHours
FROM (
    SELECT
        oh.restaurant,
        oh.delivery,
        JSON_OBJECTAGG(
            oh.dotw,
            JSON_OBJECT(
                'Openingtime', oh.start,
                'Closingtime', oh.end)) JSONoh
    FROM opening_hours oh
    GROUP BY oh.restaurant, oh.delivery) oh
GROUP BY oh.restaurant
```

Comment: Do you really get what you want? I've got quoted string instead of each nested json

Answer (score 0):

I am stuck working in MYSQL 5, so I am not familiar with the JSON_AGG functions, but you can achieve what you want using GROUP_CONCAT as follows (beware, it's clunky, and untested):

```
    SELECT r,CONCAT("{'",dt,"':'",GROUP_CONCAT(line2),"}")) as json
    FROM (
        SELECT  r,dt,CONCAT("{'",dw,"':'",GROUP_CONCAT(line1),"}") AS line2
        FROM (
            SELECT  restaurant r,delivery dt,dotw dw,CONCAT("{'start':'",start,"', 'end':'",end,"}") line1
            FROM opening_hours 
            WHERE restaurant = 665 # <<< remove this clause to include all restaurants
            ) AS SQ1
        GROUP BY r,dt,dw
        ORDER BY r,dt,dw
        ) as SQ2
    GROUP BY r,dt
    ORDER BY r,dt;
```

This answer assumes you feed the '655' into the WHERE clause of the inner subquery to get a report for a single restaurant. If you need a report for multiple restaurants, just remove the WHERE clause.

Comment: This was somewhat similar to what my second solution would've been. The innerjoin is really required to make the response a single row, correct?

Comment: @Adam, these are not inner joins. Each query is the entire data source for the level above it. I have used this approach many times to produce JSON output from pre-V8 MySQL. And yes, for every dimension in the JSON structure, you need another level in this layered SELECT, with each level adding another dimension. It's pretty clunky, and raises eyebrows amongst the purists, but it works fine, and there are no black boxes involved.

Comment: My client where I use this technique has just moved to Mariadb v10.4.12 so time for me to bone up on those JSON functions:-)

Comment: BTW, if you only have one table in your query, you really do not need to use the alias "oh" - there can be no ambiguity about which table any field belongs to.

Comment: I notice too that in your solution, you have used the alias "oh" for both the table opening_hours inside the subquery and also for the subquery as a whole in the main query. I think this is confusing. I think you should use something else for the subquery. FWIW when I have multiple nested subqueries, I always call them SQ1, SQ2... as I work my way out to the main query. Then it's very clear what comes from where.

Comment: I didn't run your exact version of the code as I didn't want to use concats and group concats (even though they are exactly the same as a json_object(agg), however I did get inspired by your way of using the query and used it to find the solution. I'm glad your client finally upgraded! Using JSON_ statements makes it so much easier.